# Reading a file and calculating averages in Lua

Tags: file, lua

What I have to do as a homework is to read a file with Lua, and make an average of work hours in a week for the hours inside the file.

I only have to count the time from a log-in event to the next log-out event.

The file looks like this

```
``
07:50:17 [6597] log-in
08:16:23 [6597] phone-call
08:50:02 [6597] deposit
09:10:08 [6597] withdraw
09:23:17 [6597] deposit
09:51:17 [6597] phone-call
10:02:27 [6597] phone-call
10:03:40 [6597] phone-call
10:19:12 [6597] phone-call
10:39:51 [6597] deposit
11:05:59 [6597] deposit
11:15:24 [6597] withdraw
11:20:54 [6597] withdraw
11:22:13 [6597] deposit
11:43:33 [6597] withdraw
11:59:47 [6597] phone-call
12:18:49 [6597] phone-call
12:21:05 [6597] phone-call
12:38:22 [6597] phone-call
12:49:52 [6597] withdraw
12:56:57 [6597] deposit
13:29:01 [6597] phone-call
13:48:40 [6597] withdraw
14:08:18 [6597] phone-call
14:39:01 [6597] withdraw
15:09:02 [6597] deposit
15:27:20 [6597] phone-call
15:31:25 [6597] deposit
15:54:54 [6597] deposit
16:18:21 [6597] phone-call
16:19:05 [6597] deposit
16:27:41 [6597] withdraw
16:32:13 [6597] withdraw
16:44:28 [6597] withdraw
16:52:49 [6597] withdraw
17:10:17 [6597] deposit
17:35:18 [6597] phone-call
18:06:03 [6597] log-out
``
```

but it contains entries for several days.

Comment: [So you want us to do your homework?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: And what exactly is your question? The button you clicked to create this post is labeled "Ask Question".

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't know how to get started rather than searching someone who does your homework. So I'll give you a few hints that will accelerate your progress.

If you don't have Lua on your computer:
Read this: [Lua: Getting Started](https://www.lua.org/start.html)

No, don't stop at

> Our community is friendly and will most probably help you if you need.
>   Just visit the mailing list, the chat room, and stackoverflow.

Read further.

Follow the instructions on how to install Lua.

Then read the [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/). Don't worry if you don't get everything on your first read.

Beside the knowledge about Lua's basics like syntax, operators, control statements and such you'll need to know:

- how to read a file line by line (io library, generic for loop, iterators)
- how to find character sequences in strings (string library, patterns)
- how to convert time strings into something you can use for calculations (patterns, captures)
- some basic maths

For all of these steps you'll find pleny of examples online.

If you have problems implementing a solution, present your code and as ask a distinct question.